# How to register an event using addEventSource in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

When I click on the `dayClick`, I want to add an event to the clicked date.

I have the following JS code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    center: "title", // 센터에는 타이틀 명이 오고
    left: "prev", // 왼쪽에는 < 버튼이 오고
    right: "next" // 오른쪽에는 > 버튼이 오게됌
  },
  lang: 'ko', // 달력 한글 설정
  editable: true, // 달력의 이벤트를 수정할 수 있는지 여부를 결정
  dayClick: function(date, allDay, view) // 일 클릭시 발생
    {
      var dateFormat = date.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

      if (confirm('Do you want to register as closed?')) {
        // Register event
      } else {
        alert('You Click No');
      }
    }
});
```

`//Register event` this part, how do I add the code?

I've been very careful with the "select" feature, but the functionality I want to implement is simple, so I prefer using "`addEventSource`" rather than "select".

But I am a beginner of jquery and javascript, so I do not know how to write it.

Please guide me on how to write code.

And I would really appreciate it if you could give me a link to a site or question I could refer to.

(Oh, note that all title values   for events to be registered are "closed")

Comment: to add a single event, use renderEvent, not addEventSource. An event source is supposed to be a place from which you refresh events (e.g. a URL), not an event itself. Also addEventSource (or renderEvent) are not equivalent to the "select" callback. The select callback is how you receive user input. Then you turn that input into an event object, and add it to the calendar using the renderEvent method. So it makes no sense to say you "prefer" addEventSource/renderEvent rather than select. They are designed to work together, not be alternatives.

Comment: P.S. Do a "view source" on this demo page: https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.0/demos/selectable.html to see how to combine "select" and "renderEvent" in order to add events to your calendar. Is it me or did you ask about this (or something very similar) earlier, and then maybe delete it? Or was that someone else? Either way my suggestion above is the same.

Comment: OH. Now, I see your answer. It was very good information. I will check and try. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @ADyson I've seen a lot of documentation, but I do not really know how to write it. Could you make a simple example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the following options for `fullcalendar`. See [select demo](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.8.0/demos/selectable.html).

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
  var title = 'Some Event';
  var eventData = {
    title: title,
    start: start,
    end: end
  };

  if (confirm('Do you want to register as closed?')) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
  } else {
    alert('You Click No');
  }
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Setting the select callback allows the use to click and drag to select multiple dates and set an event.

To allow only single day events, restrict the user to only clicks by setting `dayClick` option for `fullcalendar` instead.

```
dayClick: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
    var title = 'Some Event';
    var eventData = {
      title: title,
      start: start,
    };

    if (confirm('Do you want to register as closed?')) {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
    } else {
      alert('You Click No');
    }

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
},
```

Comment: I've looked at the doc for renderEvent, but I do not understand it. Can you explain?

Comment: renderEvent takes two arguments the first being an [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) and the second a boolean to determine whether to set the event permanently on the calendar. 

You will however still will need to make an AJAX call to some service to persist this event because as soon as you reload the browser it will be lost. Stickness here is for keeping the added event on the calendar when navigating the calendar.

Comment: Now I understand. One more question: Why does the select: function () send start and end values? I don t think that is a necessary value.

Comment: Because you can select and drag to select more than one date.

Comment: Ah! I understand. However, in the function I want to implement, Multiple dates can not be selected. How can I prevent it?

Comment: Use a `dayClick` for that.

Comment: I failed using it. The reason is that when I clicked, I had difficulty getting the title value.

Comment: sorry for being annoying.

Comment: I will check that wait please :D